# Is there a way to prevent loading of specific datasets from the datasets package?

Tags: r, dataset

On start-up, R 3.6.7 loads `stats`, `graphics`, `grDevices`, `datasets`, `methods` and `base` packages.

I'm specifically interested in removing the datasets in `datasets` related to the US states (state.names, etc.), as they screw up autocompletion in most of my projects, which involve, e.g., Australian or Indian states, and have similarly named variables.

Is there a straightforward way of preventing only those few datasets from loading? I don't want to remove the full package because who doesn't need an `mtcars`-based test every now and then.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: In your startup file, you could add: `data(mtcars); detach(package:datasets)`. Maybe add `iris` for good measure.

Comment: @Edward, did you want to put this as an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your startup file, you could add:

```
data(mtcars)
detach(package:datasets)
```

Maybe also add the `iris` data since it has a "factor" variable.